# facebook form post to php

Tags: php, facebook

I made a facebook form (Static FBML), and I posting data to my process.php. Its works great, but the special language characters doesn't works well, whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`utf8_decode`](http://www.php.net/utf8_decode) solved the issue.